# Issue while comparing the decimal column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point

I have below dataframe with 2 columns, dtypes: object for both columns

```
    TYP             T_TYP
0   181.23876781111 181.23876751111
1   273.98111182222 273.98111182222
2   123456575765776 889.53543543444
3   343.56TUUY87888 646546545454555
4   CGDYTFYFYHGC    455.YTTFGCFTTCT
5   0.0             123.5646546
6   local           68.46
7   TNT005          908
```

First I am using a regular expression to check if both columns should have the data in decimal format and all numbers using

```
exp = '^(\d+\.)+\d+$'
df['match'] = df['TYP'].str.match(exp) & df['T_TYP'].str.match(exp)
df
```

My resultant dataframe is like below now

```
    TYP             T_TYP           match
0   181.23876781111 181.23876751111 True
1   273.98111182222 273.98111182222 True
2   123456575765776 889.53543543444 False
3   343.56TUUY87888 646546545454555 False
4   CGDYTFYFYHGC    455.YTTFGCFTTCT False
5   0.0             123.5646546     True
6   local           68.46           False
7   TNT005          908             False
```

On the dataframe, I need to check if the match column value is True, then for that row compare the value for both columns TYP and T_TYP. The whole part of the value should match and the fraction part should match till 6th decimal place. If the 7th decimal place does not match then show it as a mismatch. I tried numpy where method but it is always giving me error saying ** TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' **. I did not understand why this is happening.

Requesting some help on this issue.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @piRSquared I think the `match` column is already there with the provided code. I think OP wants to compare the numbers upto 6th decimal digit, but wasn't entierly sure.

Comment: @QuangHoang... we can add one more column which says True if value for both columns mismatch at 7th decimal place else False

Comment: @piRSquared....compare the column values for those rows which has True value in match column, else ignore.

Comment: `df['diff'] = None` and `(df.loc[df.match == True, 'diff'] = df[match == True]['TYP'].astype('float64') - df[match == True]['T_TYPE].astype('float64')).abs()`. Then `df[df.diff <= 10**-7]` is what you're looking for

Comment: I tried this  **df = df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.TYP.astype(float64).round(7) == x.T_TYP.astype(float64).round(7)) if x.match == True else False, axis=1)**
df  and this also not working and complaining <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
df['output'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['TYP'], errors='coerce')
   .sub(pd.to_numeric(df['T_TYP'], errors='coerce'))
   .abs()<1e-6
)
```

Output:

```
               TYP            T_TYP  output
0  181.23876781111  181.23876751111    True
1  273.98111182222  273.98111182222    True
2  123456575765776  889.53543543444   False
3  343.56TUUY87888  646546545454555   False
4     CGDYTFYFYHGC  455.YTTFGCFTTCT   False
5              0.0      123.5646546   False
6            local            68.46   False
7           TNT005              908   False
```

Comment: Since `apply` applies to a function across each column (by default), you can use it to apply `pd.to_numeric` without the usual `apply` shaming (-: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').pipe(lambda d: np.isclose(d['TYP'], d['T_TYP']))`

Comment: The gross golfed version of that is `np.isclose(*map(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').get, df))`

Comment: Perfect.. let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: @Quang Hoang... the solution you gave, worked for me, but I am trying to understand what exactly it is doing. Would you be able to help me to understand this?

Comment: @sac `pd.to_numeric` converts the columns to numbers, mark `nan` where it's not a number (equivalent to your `.str.match`). Then compare those two number columns with a threshold of `1e-6=0.000001`, that is, if the difference is less than 1e-6 then it's a match; the two numbers matches upto  6th decimal digit.

Comment: @Quang Hoang... the solution you gave, worked for me for a smaller dataset,, but when I applied it on my actual dataset, it is giving me True for all values, even though there are not mismatch.

Comment: Can you provide example? Do they look like `0.1234567` and `0.123457`? My solution would say this is a match.

Comment: I have value like TYP(00000001.0368621) and T_TYP(1.0368621) so as per logic all the digits after the decimal are same so it is not a mismatch and should return False, but it is returning True. There are many such examples.

Comment: @QuangHoang.... as per my requirement 0.1234567 and 0.123457 should not be a match. 
My requirement says 0.1234567 and 0.1234568 a mismatch(True) because the 7th decimal place is different. 
For another scenario 0.1234567 and 0.1234567 is a complete match(False) because all digits are matching. 
Another scenario 1.2457810 and 1.2457809 should come as False because the first 6 digits are not matching so it will considered it as a match(False)
and if all digits are different then also it should come as False.

Comment: @QuangHoang..can you please assist on this issue? I know definitely your solution works, but not getting the understanding why it is not working on my data.